# Flutter - How to create these custom Container shape?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to create a custom shape `Container` in Flutter. Here's how it looks like:

[image: The picture of the shape]

Does anyone know how to create those kinds of `Container` shapes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make a custon `ShapeBorder` class and use it in `ShapeDecoration`

Comment: is there any advantage of using ShapeBorder and ShapeDecoration or is it just easier than customPaint?